# Moderator Pro-Tem Nominations

Tags: discusión, moderación

This is the post is for nominations for [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) for this site.  I won't go into too much detail about pro-tem moderators specifically.  But if you're not familiar with them, [read this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Some points to note:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer with the name of the nominee (which should be a link to the user’s profile).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”
- Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

I feel that it is very important to note that these nominations are taken into account by StackExchange. However, the SE Staff (and they alone) determine the pro-tem moderators. Votes are important, though, in showing community support.

Comment: I would love to see some more nominations here--especially of native Spanish speakers.  I can go through the users on the site to make some of my own nominations, but I'd rather see some self-nominations and/or nominations of friends, as I think this will make for more valuable nominations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pro Tem moderators have been announced](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/12).

Thanks for the suggestions folks, and see you all when we hold live elections!

Answer (score 11):

### [Gonzalo Medina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/157/gonzalo-medina)

I am a mathematician and also a native Spanish speaker from Colombia. I arrived about 8 months ago to StackExchange through [TeX.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) where I've been really active (33+ rep.).

I've also actively participated here. I insist on a good use of Spanish and really like the idea of a site like this one.

Feel free to ask if you want to know anything else about me.

Comment: 33k+ rep, at that!

Comment: Humility seems to be another of Gonzalo's virtues (-;

Comment: I had a look through your questions and answers they seem pretty good but my Spanish isn't good enough to read the ones in Spanish so well. I see this is actually your first post here in meta though. I would like to see you much more active in Meta since that's where mods will spend a lot of their time and it's important for site development and maintenance.

Comment: @hippietrail: Now I know why you haven't accepted my answers to some of your questions ;-) Will try to provide an English translation as soon as I can. About my participation in meta, yes, this is my first post here; however I frequently visit the meta site and read the question and answers. I'll be more active (independently of whether I will be appointed Mod. or not).

Comment: Sometimes I also let my questions stew for a while to see what bubbles up after some voting and commenting before I do the big "accept". Especially when my own knowledge isn't good enough to make the final decision and/or when definitive/canonical references are lacking. But let me go look at my questions to see what else I can accept...

Comment: @hippietrail: I was just joking.

Comment: You were right though. I have accepted quite a few more answers now though some were still not "ripe enough".

Comment: I second this nomination. Good luck Gonzalo!

Answer (score 8):

### [Flimzy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12/flimzy)

I feel like he has been a solid supporter of this community from the beginning.  I've seen his participation on other SE sites and have valued his opinion.  He always seems to come at things from a right perspective.

Some sample questions:

- [When to use ya and todavía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/38/when-to-use-ya-and-todavia)
- [Significance of adjective placement](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/328/significance-of-adjective-placement)
- [Proper spelling of “beisbol”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/242/proper-spelling-of-beisbol) (with picture!)

Meta posts:

- [When are answers without sources acceptable?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/when-are-answers-without-sources-acceptable)
- Answer to [Are word translation questions on topic?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12/3)
- Answer to [How are we going to deal with spanish regional variations?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/3)

I believe he is a strong candidate for this position and that he would be an excellent asset to this community.

---

As suggested in the blog post mentioned in the question, I am editing this answer to say a little about myself, and accept the nomination, if the community should decide to go that direction.

First, let me say for anyone who doesn't already know from my participation on the site, I am not an expert Spanish speaker.  However, I am highly motivated to continue learning Spanish.  I moved to Mexico (from Kansas, USA) a year and a half ago to improve my Spanish skills.  Hopefully that says something about my level of dedication to this subject matter.

In the interest of full disclosure, I should say I will be returning to the U.S. in January 2012 for personal reasons. Although I intend to remain involved in learning Spanish, and the Spanish-speaking community in my home town (which is significant).

I've been involved with SE for over 3 years (originally on SO), and in the last 6 months or so my participation has greatly increased across a wide variety of SE sites.  I would be pleased to take the next step in SE involvement by becoming a pro-tem moderator for this site.

Answer (score 7):

### [hippietrail](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/75/hippietrail)

He has been quite active on the main site, as well as meta and chat.  My interactions with him have shown that he has a healthy concern for the well-being of this site, and I believe a good understanding of what makes an SE site work.  He also has a level of patience with new visitors to the site that I admire, and think will make for an invaluable asset to this community.

---

Well I guess I should accept then - thank you for the nomination (-:

So the story is I'm not immersed in Spanish right now. I'm from Australia and I'm a world traveller. I first learned Spanish starting in Mexico in I think January 2006 with a Lonely Planet Mexican Spanish Phrasebook I bought on the way to boarding my flight in Vancouver. That trip I stayed 6 months in Mexico and Guatemala but I've had five more trips to Mexico since then, lasting between 3 to 12 months each time.

I've been travelling in the following Spanish-speaking countries: Costa Rica, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, Mexico, Nicaragua, Panama, and Spain. I've also made use of it in Andoraa, Belize and Morocco somehow.

In my travels I collect strange words, especially for local foods. I also look out for strange words when reading in Spanish. I also have a collection of Spanish dictionaries. Three big fat ones plus a small selection of regional ones from Central America. None are anywhere near me now though because I'm living in Tbilisi, Georgia for a few months!

Some people tell me I'm fluent but I think I'm not. Also I'm an "armchair" linguist. Never studied but I've been reading about languages and linguistics in books and Internet for years so I can help clear up some issues with terminology and linguistics - but I'm aware that I'm sometimes wrong.

I'm most active on Stack Exchange right now on Travel but from time to time also on English Language & Usage, Linguistics, Japanese Language & Usage, and a couple of others so I know how the stuff on the site works. Anyway that's enough talking about myself, come and talk to me [in the Spanish Language & Usage chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/spanish-language-and-usage)!

Comment: I'm generally considered too controversial or something to be an SE mod but thank you (-: (hopefully I come across as friendlier in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/spanish-language-and-usage) than I sometimes can in comments though) I will have loads of free time to help out for the next few months though.

Comment: @hippietrail I'll second Flimzy's nomination of you. Your participation on this site has been exemplary in my view.

Answer (score 7):

### [Joze](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/110/joze)

Hello hello to everyone!! For those who don't know me: I am 22, Colombian (so a native speaker), student in Computer Science and Mathematics in Strasbourg.

I am an avid reader and writer: reader in French, English, and Spanish, but writer mostly in Spanish. This is why I want to participate in the understanding of the nuances of Spanish. Why? Because I think it's a win-win, allows me to meet people that shares my interest in the language, to learn by answering questions and to ask questions that bug me while writing.

So far in the 20 days I have been in SL&U (at the time of this post writing) I have learned a lot in this time and it's because of this that I have a genuine interest on the well-being of the site.

Ask me questions about myself and I will be happy to answer them!!

Comment: Good luck to you too!