# Stepping down as moderator (Flimzy)

Tags: discusión, moderación

Good day everyone.  After [something like 7 years as pro-tem moderator](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) on this site, the time has come for me to step down as moderator. I hope you will all participate in helping to select a replacement through the new [moderator election](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3123/12).

Since this site began, my life has changed significantly. I was living in Mexico when I accepted the role. I've since moved countries more than once, ending in the Netherlands for now.  I've gotten married (to a native Spanish speaker!).  I've changed jobs many times.

Although I still speak Spanish at home on occasion, my involvement in the Spanish language has waned significantly, since I no longer live in a Spanish-speaking country.

I've also been delighted to see this site take a more Spanish-first approach.

All this to say, I no longer feel I'm the right person to help lead this site where it needs to go next, and other time commitments have been pulling me away.

I will, of course, remain a member of the community, and look forward to stopping by now and again, possibly with questions and answers.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you for all the important work you have done as a moderator, specially in the early days of the site.

Comment: Gracias Flimzy !!! Hiciste un gran trabajo.

Comment: Both you and @fedorqui have always left a favorable impression on me.  It is sad to see you depart from your positions as moderators, but I am sure your reasons are sound and just.  I still hope to see you contribute to Spanish Stack Exchange.  Your contributions are always welcome by me and I am sure many others feel the same way.  Thank you for all that you've done and will continue to do in the future.  ¡Mil gracias!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks Flimzy! Wow, 7 years is quite a lot...

Every now and then I have found myself looking for some ideas about the site, checking how some things should be handled or rules applied. Quite often, I found one of yours answers in Meta that would then provide a big sense of common sense. That helped me a lot and, in general, I think the community owes you a lot for helping it grow from a tiny Private Beta into something quite big. Not to say the big batch of questions and answers you have been posting through the years.

Hopefully you will continue providing good insights in Meta... and please, remember that this site is here to help when you step into the Spanish language again!

Answer (score 8):

Respuesta en español para que no se te oxide :D

Gracias de corazón por tu labor, esfuerzo y todo el tiempo que le has dedicado al sitio.
Cuando yo llegué aquí, tú ya estabas inmerso en ese proceso de cambios en tu vida, y por ese motivo no hemos tenido la oportunidad de interactuar mucho. Sin embargo, leyendo antiguas preguntas y respuestas (¡y [salas de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1849/2011/11/24)!) tanto en Main como en Meta, he podido ser testigo en diferido de cómo ayudaste a crear y hacer crecer el sitio, de los primeros debates sobre normas y alcance del sitio (traducciones, gramática...), de cómo enfocasteis la disyuntiva español / inglés... Una tarea encomiable gracias a la cual somos un stack, aun siendo Beta, más grande y activo que muchos otros ya graduados.

Gracias también por la generosidad que demuestras cediendo tu sitio.
La vida cambia, para todos (y añadiría: por suerte). A veces las circunstancias no nos dejan dedicarle siquiera un rato a algo que nos gusta; otras veces, son nuestras prioridades las que cambian, y preferimos dedicar nuestro tiempo —lo más valioso que tenemos, pues es lo único que no podemos recuperar una vez gastado— a otras cosas, distintas de las que hace apenas unos años nos apasionaban.
Cuando estos cambios ocurren, lo fácil, lo cómodo es agarrarse a lo que teníamos antes, ya sea algo material o a un estatus social: esa raqueta de tenis que seguimos guardando aunque nuestras rodillas no nos permitan jugar; ese telescopio relegado al estante más alto para hacer sitio a los triciclos de los niños; ese puesto en la junta directiva de la asociación de senderismo, aunque haga años que no sales de ruta y solo vayas a una de cada diez reuniones... Son parte de lo que somos o hemos sido, y nos gusta verlos, y también mostrarlos a otros, para que conozcan nuestra historia. Por eso lo difícil es vender la raqueta, regalar el telescopio o ceder tu puesto en la directiva. Hacerlo requiere claridad de pensamiento, responsabilidad y objetividad, y con este gesto demuestras estar sobrado de ambas. De nuevo, gracias.

Te deseo lo mejor en tu presente y tu futuro y, por supuesto, espero seguir viéndote por aquí (no serías el primero que, a raíz de abandonar un puesto de responsabilidad, de repente se siente liberado para participar más activamente en el sitio ;)

Comment: Un comentario así apoya aun más mi creencia que serías un moderador impresionante.  Pero, a veces, los caprichos del destino pueden ser bendiciones disfrazadas.  Me alegra que seas parte de esta comunidad y espero que sigas contribuyendo donde puedas.  Tienes mi apoyo.