# Stepping down as moderator - Renunciando como moderador (Joze)

Tags: discusión, moderación

¡Buenas buenas a todos! Después de mucho tiempo, [me doy cuenta ya 7 años](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), es mi turno de dar mi lugar de moderador a manos más motivadas para el rol. Espero que todos participen en las [próximas elecciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3123/12).

Al comienzo de este sitio, la emoción fue inmensa. Finalmente el sitio de español abre sus puertas. Para mí el sitio tenía (y tiene) un potencial inmenso. Mi pasión por esta lengua no ha cambiado, pero mi vida (por fortuna, según como uno lo vea) ha cambiado mucho. En 7 años terminé de estudiar ingeniería y arquitectura (de software) y tengo un trabajo que me apasiona en Francia.

Estoy muy alegre de ver que el sitio salió de su estatus de beta.

**¡ENHORABUENA!**

Lastimosamente no tengo tanto tiempo como antes para continuar la animación de esta comunidad, mis prioridades han cambiado. Ya desde hace casi 2 años que el tiempo para el sitio se ha vuelto escaso. Lo sospechaban me imagino, pero es por esto que es hora de entregar la antorcha de moderador.

Por supuesto voy a continuar a venir y ver como la comunidad ha cambiado, talvez responder a una o dos preguntas, aportar mi grano de arena.

¡Felicitaciones a todos por salir de beta! Nos vemos en el chat, en un thread de comentarios, o quién sabe, en otra comunidad.

¡Hasta pronto!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu tiempo Joze! Hemos coincidido poco, pues cuando yo llegué a la moderación tú debías ya estar bastante jaleo por tu parte. En cualquier caso, fue un placer debatir temas contigo y disfrutar de tu conversación en general. Mucho éxito y ojalá te veamos con frecuencia por aquí (no te nos vayas a la competencia de [french.se] :P)

Comment: Gracias Joze !!! Excelente trabajo.